# How do I make a if statement that checks message id ? (Discord PY)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I have a discord bot that gives roles when a user reacts with a special emoji on a specefic message, but the problem is that it's giving roles whenever a user reacts with those emojis on whatever message.
I have tried to make an if statement that checks the message-id but it did not work do anyone how to fix?

The if statement:

```
 if payload.message_id != 669082231955783707:
                print('[Error] Wrong message id {0.display_name}'.format(member))
```

The bot logs:

The whole code:

```
import discord
from discord import utils
 
import config
 
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
            
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
       
            if payload.message_id != 669082231955783707:
                print('[Error] Wrong message id {0.display_name}'.format(member))
            
            if (len([i for i in member.roles if i.id in config.ROLES.values()]) < config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role)) 

            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
    

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) 
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) 
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) 
       
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) 
            
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
        
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
 
# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just add `return` in your `if` statement:

```py
if payload.message_id != 669082231955783707:
    print('[Error] Wrong message id {0.display_name}'.format(member))
    return
```

By doing so, your `on_raw_reaction_add` function will stop when someone reacts on the wrong message.